# Which kind of JOIN statement can reproduce the Oracle MERGE statement?

Tags: oracle, join, merge

I'm looking for a SELECT - JOIN statement that can reproduce exactly the MERGE statement, in order to visualize the exact match that is done between the SOURCE table and the TARGET table.

In other way, which kind of JOIN is?
FULL JOIN? FULL OUTER JOIN? INNER JOIN? And so on.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're most likely looking for an outer join of the target table to the source dataset. Since all the source rows are considered for a merge statement that uses an insert and an update, you need to select all rows from the source dataset along with any matching rows from the target table.

Answer (score 1):

Take a statement:

```
MERGE INTO destination dst
USING source src
ON ( dst.some_columns = src.some_columns )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET columns_to_update = dst.columns_to_update_from
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT ( some_columns, columns_to_update )
  VALUES ( dst.some_columns, dst.columns_to_update_from )
```

This could be a `FULL OUTER JOIN`:

```
SELECT COALESCE( dst.some_columns, src.some_columns ) AS some_columns,
       NVL2( dst.some_columns, dst.columns_to_update_from, columns_to_update )
         AS columns_to_update
FROM   source src
       FULL OUTER JOIN destination dst
       ON ( dst.some_columns = src.some_columns )
```

Or it could be an `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and `UNION`:

```
-- WHEN MATCHED OR WHEN NOT MATCHED IN DESTINATION
SELECT src.some_columns,
       NVL2( dst.some_columns, dst.columns_to_update_from, columns_to_update )
         AS columns_to_update
FROM   source src
       LEFT OUTER JOIN destination dst
       ON ( dst.some_columns = src.some_columns )
UNION ALL
-- WHEN NOT MATCHED IN SOURCE
SELECT some_columns,
       columns_to_update_from
FROM   destination dst
WHERE  NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                    FROM   source src
                    WHERE  ( dst.some_columns = src.some_columns ) )
```

Or it could be an `INNER JOIN` and `UNION`s:

```
-- WHEN MATCHED
SELECT src.some_columns,
       dst.columns_to_update_from AS columns_to_update
FROM   source src
       INNER JOIN destination dst
       ON ( dst.some_columns = src.some_columns )
UNION ALL
-- WHEN NOT MATCHED IN DESTINATION
SELECT some_columns,
       columns_to_update
FROM   source src
WHERE  NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                    FROM   destination dst
                    WHERE  ( dst.some_columns = src.some_columns ) )
UNION ALL
-- WHEN NOT MATCHED IN SOURCE
SELECT some_columns,
       columns_to_update_from
FROM   destination dst
WHERE  NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                    FROM   source src
                    WHERE  ( dst.some_columns = src.some_columns ) )
```